# configure nginx log_format in sites-enabled

Tags: nginx, configuration

I have a log_format configuration I want to enable.
The thing is that our installation adds a file to sites-enabled (or conf.d) in the nginx directory and we don't touch nginx.conf itself

I want to keep it that way (easier when upgrading nginx versions are so on)

From what I understand `log_format` can only be done in the `http` section which is in nginx.conf

What are my options?

Answer (score 3):

I know this late coming, but you can just put log_format outside of your server scope in your site.

```
log_format test '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $request_time "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

server {
    listen 80;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access-test.log test;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

believe the quick and dirty one will be to use `include`
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/#nginx-conf
https://kcode.de/wordpress/2033-nginx-configuration-with-includes

Comment: It doesn't help in keeping nginx.conf original and not patching it during install. What I'm looking for is a way to augment http in a different file. Not sure it is possible